# How to filter openshift pods using go lang template option?

Tags: command-line-interface, openshift

When doing `oc get pods`, you'll get a result like the one below

```
NAME                                                 READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
x-processor-v1-0-0-snapshot-12-build                 0/1       Completed   0          24d
y-processor-v1-0-0-snapshot-5-deploy                 0/1       Error       0          10d
x-processor-v1-0-0-snapshot-13-build                 0/1       Completed   0          23d
```

I would like to get the same output format however I need to filter the output by just showing pods that has STATUS == Error. Its easy if all I need is to get the pods that are running

```
oc get pods --show-all=false
```

I've started looking at -o go-template option, but admittedly this is my first time using the go template. What I've come up with is the one below, but there are parts missing (i already did a oc get pod podName -o json to see the structure and be able to get the information that i need, but i didnt get the Ready and Age values) and obviously it doesn't run. I would appreciate if anyone can lead me to the right direction. Thanks.

```
oc get pods -o=go-template=‘{{range $pod := .items}}{{println “NAME READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE”}}{{if eq $pod.status.phase == “Error”}} {{.metadata.name}}{{where to get ready field like 0/1}}{{.status.phase}}{{.status.containerStatuses.restartCount}}{{where to get age}}{{end}}’ | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

Go templating is useful for filtering snippets from output, but I think you might simplify this with the following:

`oc get po --field-selector=status.phase=Error`